# Is there other options for date & time form fields in CakePHP beyond just min/max?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Example - I'd like the [start_date][year] field to go from smallest to largest, top to bottom instead of bottom to top.

Another example - I'd like the minutes to be every 5 minutes instead of every minute.

Obviously I could just write my own form fields using HTML, but - thought I'd first ask if it's possible with Cake form options.  I found 'minYear' and 'maxYear'...was hoping there'd be other options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the big ones I was looking for was the "minutes to be every 5 minutes instead of every minute".  This one IS available by setting the field option:  `'interval'=>5`

At the moment, it doesn't appear the other option(s) are available.

Answer (score 1):

Other than dateFormat/timeFormat, there are no other options for configuring those.  You'll have to write your own option sets.

Comment: Thanks as always, Tyler.  I wish you had a different answer for me, but...  I'll let you slide with the "correct" answer this time. ;)